# How To apply UIGestureRecognizerDelegate On UIView Instead of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Hi all I am doing pinch zoom & pan on UIImageView which is inside a **UIView** for this I have written code which is working fine . My problem is when i am rotation OR pinching the image,it's not rotating OR panning from **centre** part of images. If i am doing same code on **UIViewController**  this code is working great for Rotation & panning also .Please help me what i have mistaken here

in **GestureRecognizer_UIView.h** file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>   
@interface GestureRecognizer_UIView : UIView<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;                                                                                @property CGFloat lastRotation;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
@end
```

In GestureRecognizer_UIView.m file

```
#import "GestureRecognizer_UIView.h" 

@implementation GestureRecognizer_UIView  
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame  
{  
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];  
    if (self)              
{
        // Initialization code    
    }  
    return self;  
}  
-(void)awakeFromNib   
{           
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationG = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] 

 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationImage:)];   

    rotationG.delegate = self;
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecongnizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:)];
    pinchGestureRecongnizer.delegate = self;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panpan:)];
    panGesture.delegate = self;
   [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecongnizer];
    [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:rotationG];     
    [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];



}       
- (void)panpan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender       {
    [self bringSubviewToFront:_imageView];   
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self];
    CGPoint imageViewPosition = _imageView.center;
    imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
    imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;
   _imageView.center = imageViewPosition;
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];

}
-(void)rotationImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    [self bringSubviewToFront:gesture.view];    
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self];
    gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);    
    if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        self.lastRotation = 0;
        return;
    }
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = _imageView.transform;
    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (self.lastRotation - gesture.rotation);
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, rotation);
    _imageView.transform = newTransform;
    self.lastRotation = gesture.rotation;
}

- (void)changeImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinchGestureRecognizer {
    [self bringSubviewToFront:pinchGestureRecognizer.view];

    CGPoint location = [pinchGestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
     pinchGestureRecognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);    
    pinchGestureRecognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinchGestureRecognizer.view.transform, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
 pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1;            
}    



- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer     *)otherGestureRecognizer 

 {
    return  YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Please make sure you have enable user interaction of image view

_imageView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;